# Configuration setting for Vim PEP-8 plugin to ignore errors and warnings?

Tags: python, vim, pep8

I am using this plugin to detect PEP-8 errors and warnings in Vim:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3430

I want to ignore few errors and warnings like E501 & W601 given in the backend pep8 tool:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8

When I looked at the plugin code, I can see it has support for this:

```
from pep8checker import Pep8Checker

args = vim.eval('string(g:pep8_args)')
select = vim.eval('string(g:pep8_select)')
ignore = vim.eval('string(g:pep8_ignore)')

if select:
    args = args + ' --select=%s' % select

if ignore:
    args = args + ' --ignore=%s' % ignore

pep8_checker = Pep8Checker(cmd, args)
```

But how do I use it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set the variable `g:pep8_ignore`; you should put this in your vimrc.

```
let g:pep8_ignore="E501,W601"
```

Answer (score 31):

For those folks that stumble across this question and the above answer doesn't work, here's some solutions for other Vim Python plugins:

For [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic):

```
let g:syntastic_python_checker="flake8"
let g:syntastic_python_checker_args="--ignore=E501,W601"
```

UPDATE: newer versions of Syntastic use this instead:

```
let g:syntastic_python_checkers=["flake8"]
```

For [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode):

```
let g:pymode_lint_ignore="E501,W601"
```

Ensure that these are set before Pathogen or Vundle are triggered.

Comment: thanks @robbrit!  super useful..I'm just firing up some `python-mode` configuration, and this was just what I needed

Comment: For those using python-mode, @robbrit's answer, `let g:pymode_lint_ignore="E501,W601"` did the trick for me. The vim pymode help led me towards something else.

Comment: YOU'RE THE MAN! Thanks. This answer deserves the badge for this question!

Comment: For those that want to disable all errors: `let g:pymode_lint = 0` or `:PymodeLintToggle`. I found this via `:help pymode`.

Comment: pesky python-mode E266 warnings due to doxygen wanting '##' now a memory.

Answer (score 10):

After trying all of robbrit's solutions and finding that none of them worked for me, I read some of the documentation for Syntastic. To pass args to a checker, you need to know several things. The following is the command syntax:

```
let g:syntastic_python_checkers=["<checker_type>"]

let g:syntastic_<filetype>_<checker_name>_args="--ignore=E501,W601,..."
```

This means that if you use flake8, you would write:

```
let g:syntastic_python_checkers=["flake8"]
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args="--ignore=E501,W601"
```

Hope this helps someone avoid spending ages trying to figure this out like I did.

Comment: Thanks. Just for info, be sure to use `let g:syntastic_python_checkers=["flake8"]` first, as mentioned by robbrit.

Comment: Thanks so much.. this info should be more prominent

Comment: +1:  Thank you for the precision of yr answer..  Highlighting the fact that the precise syntax of `... = '--ignore=E501,W601'` **is** important, may help others.  Writing for instance: `='--ignore = E501, W601'`  would fail silently, because of the added spaces inside the single (or double) quoted argument string. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`python-mode`](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode) you need to use list now:

```
let g:pymode_lint_ignore=["E501", "W601"]
```